# Java: How can I notify a thread only if it is waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading

In a first Java thread I have:

```
while (!isDone) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            wait();
        } 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    doSomeVeryLongRunningTask();
}
```

In another thread, I want to send a notify signal:

```
synchronized (thr1) {
    thr1.notify();
}
```

However, if the `doSomeVeryLongRunningTask()` method is running, I don't want the second thread to get blocked.  I only want to notify the first thread if it is waiting so that the second thread can continue it tasks without getting locked.

How might I fix the code above to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They problem you want to fix does not exist. `synchronized` blocks will block the thread only if another thread is already inside a `synchronized` block synchronizing *on the same object*. Since your `doSomeVeryLongRunningTask()` will be called outside the `synchronized` block the notifying thread will never get blocked if the other thread is inside the `doSomeVeryLongRunningTask()` method.

But this raises another problem. You seem to be thinking, that `wait` and `notify` invocations are always paired. This is not the case, you may call `notify` as often as you wish without anyone listening to it. It might be also the case that a `wait` invocation returns “spuriously”, i.e. for no apparent reason. You therefore need to define another “hard condition” which is defined by a state that is modified and checked inside the `synchronized` block.

E.g. inside the class whose instance you have in your `thr1` variable, you can define a `boolean` flag:

```
boolean condition;
```

Then you modify you waiting method like this:

```
while(!isDone) {
  try {
    synchronized(this) {
      while(!condition) wait();
      if(isDone) break;// skip doSomeVeryLongRunningTask()
      condition=false;
    }
  } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  doSomeVeryLongRunningTask();
}
```

And the notifying code to:

```
synchronized(thr1) {
  thr1.condition=true;
  thr1.notify();
}
```

This way your notifying code still won’t get blocked (at least never for a significant time) but the waiting thread will wait for at least one notification to happen within one loop cycle.

Comment: "The problem you want to fix does not exist." Thanks for your reply.  You helped me see one of the problems with the shortened question I provided...`doSomeVeryLongRunningTask()` was a synchronized method. I should likely remove the synchronization there.  The rest of your posted solution gives me some other ideas to try. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what is blocking your program is not the `notify()` (it doesn't block ever) but the two `synchronized` blocks that are synchronizing on the same object.

I don't think there is a workaround to what you ask. Check this link to know why: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/wait-notify-and-notifyall-in-java.html

Comment: What I basically have is a Producer-Consumer problem where the Consumer can sometimes be very slow and I don't want to stop the Producer from doing its other tasks. Does that help to potentially suggest an alternative approach to get around the situation where the Producer is stuck waiting at `synchronized(thrd1)` ?

Comment: In this case you can use an intermediary thread-safe data structure, like a Queue. Producers will insert in that queue and consumers will read from there. Look at the `java.util.concurrent` package for some Queue implementations to see which fits you the most.

Answer (score 0):

The `notify()` call doesn't block. Only `wait()` blocks. You can call notify even if there isn't another thread waiting, but then make sure your algorithm is correct. If you expect to notify only once, then another thread arriving after the notify will wait() forever.

Comment: The notify() doesn't block -- but having to synchronize on thrd1 does.  Is there a better way to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

The advised pattern is to use notifyAll() AND to have ALL waiting threads check their wake-up condition each time they are notified AND before starting the first Wait.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronized in modern Java is about as fast as `--i`, because this is about what is internally happening thanks to hardware `compareAndSet` mechanisms. The only moment this slows down noticeably, is when more than one thread is arriving at the synchronized block and therefore at least one has to wait.