# How to compare with Thread State

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to threads,How to check If the thread is in waiting state,If it is in waiting state only then i needed to notify it.

For Ex: there is a thread named 's' ,when it is invoked wait state then only the notify status must be invoked.

Is there any possibility to get that using getState() command

For Ex:

```
if(s.getState()=="WAITING")//To have a condition block like this
```

Comment: Regarding, `if (x == "WAITING")` -- Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  My question is How can we compare Thread.State with a String ,I am sorry if i have conveyed wrongly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How can I notify a thread only if it is waiting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270122/java-how-can-i-notify-a-thread-only-if-it-is-waiting)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels its not duplicate,because i have asked invoking wait state ,whereas in the above mentioned link it spoke related to notify() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Thread.State enum type, which is what you get when you call getState() on a thread. The following code could be helpful.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread.State state = t1.getState();
System.out.println(state.equals(Thread.State.NEW));
// or 
if (Thread.getState().equals(Thread.State.WAITING) {}
```

Comment: But is it even necessary? The question looks to be how to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: I had that feeling but this is what is being asked. Maybe it is just experimenting.